# Is it possible to use useEmailAsUsername and see User Relations Fields display as First Name + Last Name?

Tags: users, relations

We have a site where we want to use email addresses as the username.

The site also has a lot of related user content and the administrators on the site know many of the site members by name.

Currently, Craft User Relations Fields display the email address of each user.  This gets pretty confusing quick as recognizable names become long strings of letters and numbers after you relate them.  In some cases, we find ourselves triggering the User Relations modal just to figure out who is related to the Entry we are looking at.

We require Users to submit First Name and Last Name values so we can ensure that each user has that value. Is there any way to define what values we see for the User Relations Fields?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there isn't a native way to do that, but I can see where it'd get confusing.  I'll add it to our list to look into.